# php in array returning false when value does exist

Tags: php, arrays

Simple one here, but hurting ones head.

```
echo in_array('275', $searchMe);
```

is returning false. But if I print the array out and then search it manually using my web browser I am able to see that the value exists in the array.

```
[0] => ExtrasInfoType Object
                (
                    [Criteria] => 
                    [Code] => 275
                    [Type] => 15
                    [Name] => Pen
                )
```

Extra information. The array has been coverted from an object to an array using

```
$searchMe = (array) $object;
```

Would it be because the values are not quoted? I have tried using the following with the `in_array` function:

```
echo in_array('275', $searchMe); // returns false
echo in_array(275, $searchMe); // returns error (Notice: Object of class Extras could not be converted to int in)
```

var_dump of $searchMe

```
array
  'Extras' => 
    object(Extras)[6]
      public 'Extra' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(ExtrasInfoType)[7]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(ExtrasInfoType)[17]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(ExtrasInfoType)[27]
              ...
```

Comment: Dump that array after the conversion, did it retain the associative keys for the properties of the object, or did it convert the properties to numeric indexes?  If it worked at all.

Comment: Note that error indicates that `$searchMe` is still an object.

Comment: ok. so in_array will not work on objects?

Comment: @claw: Seeing as how objects are not arrays, probably not, unless you can convert it properly.

Comment: @claw `in_array()`, funnily enough, works on arrays :). You can however cast objects to arrays to turn their property/values into an associative array.

Comment: @claw: Try [get_object_vars()](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: @claw: Your modified `var_dump($searchMe)` shows that it contains a top-level, `in_array()` is not recursive, and nor is a cast.  You would need to write a custom routine for that.

Comment: right...i did a var_dump & get_object_vars on both the converted and original. Both returned the same output. Going to be a long day

Answer (score 1):

One scenario I think that would be helpful.

If the array index that contains the value is 0, the returning value of in_array would be 0. If in our logic, 0 is considered as false, then there will be issues. Avoid this pattern in your code.

Comment: I agree with you, I have just encountered the case of index 0 and in_array return false. 
Might be use strict mode also help me in this case.
 But instead I use array_search comparable to! == false

Comment: This should be a programming anti-pattern, or languages should know how to handle this. :)

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` can't see inside the `ExtrasInfoType Object`. Basically its comparing `ExtrasInfoType Object` to `275`, which in this case returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object there, use...

```
// Setup similar object
$searchMe = new stdClass;
$searchMe->Criteria = '';
$searchMe->Code = 275;
$searchMe->Type = 15;
$searchMe->Name = 'Pen';

var_dump(in_array('275', (array) $searchMe)); // bool(true)
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/x01i6PPA).

When I cast (`(array)`) to an array, I got...

```
array(4) {
  ["Criteria"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Code"]=>
  int(275)
  ["Type"]=>
  int(15)
  ["Name"]=>
}
```